# How to get click event on images which is placed on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have create program to display multiple images on canvas. Now I want to get that images data using mouse click event which is placed on canvas.
My JavaScript cod is -

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 720;
canvas.height = 480;

//I got images data in one array 
var imageobj = new Array();
for (var d=0;d<calloutImageArray.length;d++)
{
    imageobj[d] = new Image();
    (function(d)
     imageobj[d].src = sitePath+"ATOM/chapter1/book/"+calloutImageArray[d];
     imageobj[d].onload = function() 
      {
        ctx.drawImage(imageobj[d], calloutImageArrayX[d], calloutImageArrayY[d],calloutImageArrayW[d], calloutImageArrayH[d]);
      }; 
   })(d);
}
```

Comment: apart from answer by @markE you can as well use canvas libraries e.g. kineticjs. See the mouse detection in a shape: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-path-mouseover/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fairly easily done:**

- Listen for mousedown events using `canvas.addEventListener`
- On mousedown, check if the mouse is inside any image.
- Get the image data for the image under the mouse.

**Example code:**

```
function handleMousedown(e){

    // tell the browser we're handling this event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    // get the mouse position
    var mouseX=e.clientX-BBoffsetX;
    var mouseY=e.clientY-BBoffsetY;

    // loop through each image and see if mouse is under
    var hit=-1;
    for(var i=0;i<imageobj.length;i++){
        var x=calloutImageArrayX[i];
        var y=calloutImageArrayY[i];
        var w=calloutImageArrayW[i];
        var h=calloutImageArrayH[i];
        if(mouseX>=x && mouseX<=x+w && mouseY>=y && mouseY<=y+h){
            hit=i;
        }
    }

    // you clicked the image with index==hit
    // so get its image data
    if(hit>=0){
        var imageData=ctx.getImageData(
            calloutImageArrayX[hit],
            calloutImageArrayY[hit],
            calloutImageArrayW[hit],
            calloutImageArrayH[hit]);

        // now do your thing with the imageData!

    }
}
```

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var $results=document.getElementById('results');

var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
var BB,BBoffsetX,BBoffsetY;
function setBB(){
  BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  BBoffsetX=BB.left;
  BBoffsetY=BB.top;
}
setBB();
window.onscroll=function(e){ setBB(); }


var imageobj=[];
var calloutImageArrayX=[10,125,10,125];
var calloutImageArrayY=[10,10,150,150];
var calloutImageArrayW=[];
var calloutImageArrayH=[];


// put the paths to your images in imageURLs[]
var imageURLs=[];  
imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/character3.png");
imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/character2.png");
imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/character1.png");
imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stack1/avatar.png");

// the loaded images will be placed in imageobj[]
var imagesOK=0;
startLoadingAllImages(imagesAreNowLoaded);

// Create a new Image() for each item in imageURLs[]
// When all images are loaded, run the callback (==imagesAreNowLoaded)
function startLoadingAllImages(callback){

  // iterate through the imageURLs array and create new images for each
  for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
    // create a new image an push it into the imageobj[] array
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin='anonymous';
    // Important! By pushing (saving) this img into imageobj[],
    //     we make sure the img variable is free to
    //     take on the next value in the loop.
    imageobj.push(img);
    // when this image loads, call this img.onload
    img.onload = function(){ 
      // this img loaded, increment the image counter
      imagesOK++; 
      // if we've loaded all images, call the callback
      if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
        callback();
      }
    };
    // notify if there's an error
    img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
    // set img properties
    img.src = imageURLs[i];
  }      
}

// All the images are now loaded
// Do drawImage & fillText
function imagesAreNowLoaded(){

  // the imageobj[] array now holds fully loaded images
  // the imageobj[] are in the same order as imageURLs[]

  // add widths & heights to the appropriate arrays
  for(var i=0;i<imageobj.length;i++){
    calloutImageArrayW.push(imageobj[i].width);
    calloutImageArrayH.push(imageobj[i].height);
  }

  // listen for mousedown events
  canvas.onmousedown=handleMousedown;

  draw();

}


function draw(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  for(var d=0;d<imageobj.length;d++){
    ctx.drawImage(imageobj[d], 
                  calloutImageArrayX[d], calloutImageArrayY[d],
                  calloutImageArrayW[d], calloutImageArrayH[d]);
  }    
}        



function handleMousedown(e){

  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  // get the mouse position
  var mouseX=e.clientX-BBoffsetX;
  var mouseY=e.clientY-BBoffsetY;

  // loop through each image and see if mouse is under
  var hit=-1;
  for(var i=0;i<imageobj.length;i++){
    var x=calloutImageArrayX[i];
    var y=calloutImageArrayY[i];
    var w=calloutImageArrayW[i];
    var h=calloutImageArrayH[i];
    if(mouseX>=x && mouseX<=x+w && mouseY>=y && mouseY<=y+h){
      hit=i;
    }
  }

  // you clicked the image with index==hit
  // so get its image data
  if(hit>=0){
    var imageData=ctx.getImageData(
      calloutImageArrayX[hit],
      calloutImageArrayY[hit],
      calloutImageArrayW[hit],
      calloutImageArrayH[hit]);

    var pos;
    switch(hit){
      case 0:pos='top-left';break;
      case 1:pos='top-right';break;
      case 2:pos='bottom-left';break;
      case 3:pos='bottomRight';break;
    }
    $results.innerHTML='You clicked the '+pos+' image.<br>This imageData has this length: '+imageData.data.length;

  }

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<h4 id="results">Click on an image</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: I have try your answer. I am getting result but its not proper. Also I am  getting image result at below of call out image.  I want get image data on only click on that particular call out image.

Comment: @KetanPatil I've added a working demo for you to start from.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: @marksE Thanks for help. I got image details with your logic. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Take my advice and go with something like fabricJS , it will make your life very easy. In that you can easily have multiple objects on the canvas and also perform functions (Scale,rotate,pan) on them separately.

Comment: @markE i am actually using fabricjs for my project, was facing this problem when using simple canvas. Most of the problems were simplified thanks to Fabric , thats why i have suggest to use it.

Comment: No problem here! I like (and sometimes use) FabricJS--its a great framework and I would also recommend it. But my philosophy when learning is to "do once without a framework" to understand how and why things work. Cheers! ;-)

Comment: @markE cool :) ... i have a problem with fabricjs, let me know if can solve it :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002361/zoom-at-mouse-position-fabricjs