# Image zoom centered on mouse position

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, graphics, fabricjs

I am writing a script with Fabric.js to zoom an image at the current mouse position. I have made some progress but there is an error somewhere.

**Case 1**: Keep the mouse at one point and zoom with the mouse wheel.

Result: Works perfectly, image zooms at that particular pixel.

**Case 2:** Zoom in a little at one position (3-5 times with mouse wheel), then move the mouse to a new position and zoom in there.

Result: Works fine for the first point, but after moving to another point and zooming, the image position is incorrect.

My code is in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/gauravsoni/y3w0yx2m/1/

I suspect there is something wrong with the image positioning logic:

```
imgInstance.set({top:imgInstance.getTop()-newMousY,left:imgInstance.getLeft()-newMousX});
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: Why not use the canvas zoom and pan function? or youh have need to zoom just the image object and nothing else? Check this: http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink/#zoom ( use scroll to zoom )
Using the canvas zooming will allow you to zoom more object in the canvas if needed without doing calculations.
I can make a fiddle if you want to explore this possiiblity.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi i need to zoom at that particular position where the mouse is placed, the canvas scale function just scales the image

Comment: Yeah i'm talking about FABRICJS pan to point and zoom to point function. Not canvas one. I see you are using fabricjs for that.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi ah, i see. Missed this part of the documentation. Let me give this a shot

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The key to solving this puzzle is to understand how the image gets enlarged. If we're using a zoom factor of 1.2, the image becomes 20% larger. We assign 1.2 to the variable `factor` and do the following:

```js
image.setScaleX(image.getScaleX() * factor);
image.setScaleY(image.getScaleY() * factor);
```

The upper left corner of the image stays in the same place while the picture is enlarged. Now consider the point under the mouse cursor. Every pixel above and to the left of the cursor has become 20% larger. This displaces the point under the cursor by 20% downward and to the right. Meanwhile, the cursor is in the same position.

To compensate for the displacement of the point under the cursor, we move the image so that the point gets back under the cursor. The point moved down and right; we move the image up and left by the same distance.

Note that the image might have been moved in the canvas before the zooming operation, so the cursor's horizontal position in the image is `currentMouseX - image.getLeft()` before zooming, and likewise for the vertical position.

This is how we calculate the displacement after zooming:

```js
var dx = (currentMouseX - image.getLeft()) * (factor - 1),
    dy = (currentMouseY - image.getTop()) * (factor - 1);
```

Finally, we compensate for the displacement by moving the point back under the cursor:

```js
image.setLeft(image.getLeft() - dx);
image.setTop(image.getTop() - dy);
```

I integrated this calculation into your demo and made the following fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/fgLmyxw4/

I also implemented the zoom-out operation.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! i have been stuck for 2 days on this. can award bounty after 8 hrs

Comment: Can anyone implement same using canvas only? without any library?

Comment: How does one use this if the origin of the image is at the center not the top left corner?

Comment: Oh god thank you @Michael Laszlo .