# Zoom in on a mousewheel point (using scale and translate)

Tags: javascript, html, image, zooming

This question is similar to this one: [Zoom in on a point (using scale and translate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916081/zoom-in-on-a-point-using-scale-and-translate)
or even this one: [Image zoom centered on mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002361/image-zoom-centered-on-mouse-position)
but I don't want to do it on a canvas but a normal image (or rather the container div of the image).
So zooming should be as google maps.
I am actually hacking/enhancing iDangerous Swiper zoom (http://idangero.us/swiper/), and that is my starting point, and this is is what I got so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/xta2ccdt/3/

Zoom only with the mouse wheel. The first time you zoom in it zooms perfectly, but I can't figure out how to calculate every zoom after first one.

Here's my code:
JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#slideContainer").on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var delta = e.delta || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
    var zoomOut;
    if (delta === undefined) {
      //we are on firefox
      delta = e.originalEvent.detail;
      zoomOut = delta ? delta < 0 : e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0;
      zoomOut = !zoomOut;
    } else {
      zoomOut = delta ? delta < 0 : e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0;
    }
    var touchX = e.type === 'touchend' ? e.changedTouches[0].pageX : e.pageX;
    var touchY = e.type === 'touchend' ? e.changedTouches[0].pageY : e.pageY;
    var scale = 1, translateX, translateY;
    if(zoomOut){
        //we are zooming out
      //not interested in this yet
    }else{
        //we are zooming in
      scale = scale + 0.5;
      var dimensionMultiplier = scale - 0.5;//when image is scaled up offsetWidth/offsetHeight doesn't take this into account so we must multiply by scale to get the correct width/height
      var slideWidth = $("#slide")[0].offsetWidth * dimensionMultiplier;
      var slideHeight = $("#slide")[0].offsetHeight * dimensionMultiplier;

      var offsetX = $("#slide").offset().left;//distance from the left of the viewport to the slide
      var offsetY = $("#slide").offset().top;//distance from the top of the viewport to the slide
      var diffX = offsetX + slideWidth / 2 - touchX;//this is distance from the mouse to the center of the image
      var diffY = offsetY + slideHeight / 2 - touchY;//this is distance from the mouse to the center of the image

      //how much to translate by x and y so that poin on image is alway under the mouse
      //we must multiply by 0.5 because the difference between previous and current scale is always 0.5
      translateX = ((diffX) * (0.5));
      translateY = ((diffY) * (0.5));    
    }
    $("#slide").css("transform", 'translate3d(' + translateX + 'px, ' + translateY + 'px,0) scale(' + scale + ')').css('transition-duration', '300ms');
  });


});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="slideContainer">
  <div id="slide">
    <img src="http://content.worldcarfans.co/2008/6/medium/9080606.002.1M.jpg"></img>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slideContainer{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#slide{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
img{
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

I also figured out if I subtract previous translateX and translateY values from the current ones, I can zoom on the same point as much as I want and it will zoom perfectly, but if I zoom on one point and then change the mouse position and zoom in again, it will no longer zoom as it's supposed to. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/xta2ccdt/4/

If I change mouse position, and calculate the X and Y difference between old and new mouse position and add that into the diff calculation it will zoom correctly the second time. But the third time looks like that difference still gets subtracted from the total calculation and this will cause the translate to move the image away again, after that if we hold the mouse in the same position it will zoom correctly again.
So I figured I'll just add the difference between old and new mouse position every time I calculate the new "diff", and this kind of works, there is no longer a jump like it was when I stopped adding the mouse position difference, but it's still not zooming on the same position, with each new zoom it moves (offsets) the image by a small amount. I figure this is because there is a new zoom value each time, but the offset is not linear, it's everytime smaller approaching zero, and I can't figure out how to offset the offset.
Here is the new example: https://jsfiddle.net/xta2ccdt/5/
New image in the example: old one is no longer available: https://jsfiddle.net/xta2ccdt/14/

Comment: Unrelated but <img> doesn't have an end tag. It should self-close <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" /> I also had to use something like placeholder b/c the other image was blocked. I couldn't zoom out for some reason.

Comment: I found this pluging that seems to do what you want: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-for-Image-Zoom-In-Out-With-Mousewheel-imgViewer/

Comment: btw. I ended up abandoning this and used panzoom instead: https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You were close to it, however it's better to store the x,y and scale separately and calculate the transforms based on those values. It makes things alot easier + saves resources (no need to lookup the dom properties over and over),

I've put the code into a nice module:

```
function ScrollZoom(container,max_scale,factor){
    var target = container.children().first()
    var size = {w:target.width(),h:target.height()}
    var pos = {x:0,y:0}
    var zoom_target = {x:0,y:0}
    var zoom_point = {x:0,y:0}
    var scale = 1
    target.css('transform-origin','0 0')
    target.on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll",scrolled)

    function scrolled(e){
        var offset = container.offset()
        zoom_point.x = e.pageX - offset.left
        zoom_point.y = e.pageY - offset.top

        e.preventDefault();
        var delta = e.delta || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
        if (delta === undefined) {
          //we are on firefox
          delta = e.originalEvent.detail;
        }
        delta = Math.max(-1,Math.min(1,delta)) // cap the delta to [-1,1] for cross browser consistency

        // determine the point on where the slide is zoomed in
        zoom_target.x = (zoom_point.x - pos.x)/scale
        zoom_target.y = (zoom_point.y - pos.y)/scale

        // apply zoom
        scale += delta*factor * scale
        scale = Math.max(1,Math.min(max_scale,scale))

        // calculate x and y based on zoom
        pos.x = -zoom_target.x * scale + zoom_point.x
        pos.y = -zoom_target.y * scale + zoom_point.y


        // Make sure the slide stays in its container area when zooming out
        if(pos.x>0)
            pos.x = 0
        if(pos.x+size.w*scale<size.w)
            pos.x = -size.w*(scale-1)
        if(pos.y>0)
            pos.y = 0
         if(pos.y+size.h*scale<size.h)
            pos.y = -size.h*(scale-1)

        update()
    }

    function update(){
        target.css('transform','translate('+(pos.x)+'px,'+(pos.y)+'px) scale('+scale+','+scale+')')
    }
}
```

Use it by calling

```
new ScrollZoom($('#container'),4,0.5)
```

The parameters are:

1. container: The wrapper of the element to be zoomed. The script will
   look for the first child of the container and apply the transforms
   to it.
2. max_scale: The maximum scale (4 = 400% zoom)
3. factor: The zoom-speed (1 = +100% zoom per mouse wheel tick)

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/xta2ccdt/13/)

Comment: This seems to work. Why are you setting transform-origin to 0,0. I would like to leave it at 50%.50% as it is default

Comment: the logic is based on the transform origin being at x:0, y:0. But you could ofcourse modify that.

Comment: I'm having trouble modifying this for use with a transform-origin of center, what should be modified?

Comment: @Jsilvermist you need to add half of the width to the x and y coordinates. like `pos.x += size.w*scale/2`

Comment: Hmm I think I'm stupid, I can't seem to get it to work, can you give me a slightly more detailed example please? Also, thanks for sharing this awesome answer in the first place!

Comment: @Jsilvermist sure thing, breh. https://jsfiddle.net/f9kctwby/ . To be fair, it actually was `size.w*(scale-1)/2`, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will get you a little closer to what you are trying to achieve.

**Key Changes**

1. I pulled scale outside of the callback; I don't think you want to be resetting your scale on each wheel event.
2. Instead of calculating the translation manually, try setting the `transform-origin` to be centered on your mouse (unless you want to keep it centered which is the default)

```js
var scale = 1;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#slideContainer").on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var delta = e.delta || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
    var zoomOut;
    if (delta === undefined) {
      //we are on firefox
      delta = e.originalEvent.detail;
      zoomOut = delta ? delta < 0 : e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0;
      zoomOut = !zoomOut;
    } else {
      zoomOut = delta ? delta < 0 : e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0;
    }
    var touchX = e.type === 'touchend' ? e.changedTouches[0].pageX : e.pageX;
    var touchY = e.type === 'touchend' ? e.changedTouches[0].pageY : e.pageY;
    var translateX, translateY;
    if(zoomOut){
      // we are zooming out
      scale = scale - 0.01;
      
      var offsetWidth = $("#slide")[0].offsetWidth;
      var offsetHeight = $("#slide")[0].offsetHeight;

      $("#slide")
        .css("transform-origin", touchX + 'px ' + touchY + 'px')
        .css("transform", 'scale(' + scale + ')');
      
    }else{
      // we are zooming in
      scale = scale + 0.01;
      
      var offsetWidth = $("#slide")[0].offsetWidth;
      var offsetHeight = $("#slide")[0].offsetHeight;

      $("#slide")
        .css("transform-origin", touchX + 'px ' + touchY + 'px')
        .css("transform", 'scale(' + scale + ')');
    }
    
  });


});
```

```css
#slideContainer{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#slide{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
img{
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideContainer">
  <div id="slide">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200"></img>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem I'm having still remains. If you zoom e.g. somewhere in the top left corner and then zoom in the bottom right corner, the image jumps.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the answers, helped me a lot.
I have modified it to allow pan to.

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
    var scroll_zoom = new ScrollZoom($('#container'),5,0.5)
})

//The parameters are:
//
//container: The wrapper of the element to be zoomed. The script will look for the first child of the container and apply the transforms to it.
//max_scale: The maximum scale (4 = 400% zoom)
//factor: The zoom-speed (1 = +100% zoom per mouse wheel tick)

function ScrollZoom(container,max_scale,factor){
    var target = container.children().first()
    var size = {w:target.width(),h:target.height()}
    var pos = {x:0,y:0}
    var scale = 1
    var zoom_target = {x:0,y:0}
    var zoom_point = {x:0,y:0}
    var curr_tranform = target.css('transition')
    var last_mouse_position = { x:0, y:0 }
    var drag_started = 0

    target.css('transform-origin','0 0')
    target.on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll",scrolled)
    target.on('mousemove', moved)
    target.on('mousedown', function() {
        drag_started = 1;
        target.css({'cursor':'move', 'transition': 'transform 0s'});
        /* Save mouse position */
        last_mouse_position = { x: event.pageX, y: event.pageY};
    });

    target.on('mouseup mouseout', function() {
        drag_started = 0;
        target.css({'cursor':'default', 'transition': curr_tranform});
    });

    function scrolled(e){
        var offset = container.offset()
        zoom_point.x = e.pageX - offset.left
        zoom_point.y = e.pageY - offset.top

        e.preventDefault();
        var delta = e.delta || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
        if (delta === undefined) {
          //we are on firefox
          delta = e.originalEvent.detail;
        }
        delta = Math.max(-1,Math.min(1,delta)) // cap the delta to [-1,1] for cross browser consistency

        // determine the point on where the slide is zoomed in
        zoom_target.x = (zoom_point.x - pos.x)/scale
        zoom_target.y = (zoom_point.y - pos.y)/scale

        // apply zoom
        scale += delta * factor * scale
        scale = Math.max(1,Math.min(max_scale,scale))

        // calculate x and y based on zoom
        pos.x = -zoom_target.x * scale + zoom_point.x
        pos.y = -zoom_target.y * scale + zoom_point.y

        update()
    }

    function moved(event){
        if(drag_started == 1) {
            var current_mouse_position = { x: event.pageX, y: event.pageY};
            var change_x = current_mouse_position.x - last_mouse_position.x;
            var change_y = current_mouse_position.y - last_mouse_position.y;

            /* Save mouse position */
            last_mouse_position = current_mouse_position;
            //Add the position change
            pos.x += change_x;
            pos.y += change_y;

        update()
        }
    }

    function update(){
        // Make sure the slide stays in its container area when zooming out
        if(pos.x>0)
            pos.x = 0
        if(pos.x+size.w*scale<size.w)
            pos.x = -size.w*(scale-1)
        if(pos.y>0)
            pos.y = 0
        if(pos.y+size.h*scale<size.h)
            pos.y = -size.h*(scale-1)

        target.css('transform','translate('+(pos.x)+'px,'+(pos.y)+'px) scale('+scale+','+scale+')')
    }
}
```

```css
#container{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#slide{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  transition: transform .3s;
}
img{
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  max-width:100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="slide">
    <img src="https://iso.500px.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/big-one.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Test it here to if you like:
https://jsfiddle.net/Pimigo/sy9c8z5q/8/

Answer (score 1):

What about using `translate3d` and `perspective`, to handle the 3d transformations, instead of using `scale`? Also, decoupling zoom from translation makes it simpler.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var translateX = 0,
    translateY = 0,
    translateZ = 0,
    stepZ = 10,
    initial_obj_X = 0,
    initial_obj_Y = 0,
    initial_mouse_X = 0,
    initial_mouse_Y = 0;

  function apply_coords() {
    $("#slide").css("transform", 'perspective(100px) translate3d(' + translateX + 'px, ' + translateY + 'px, ' + translateZ + 'px)');
  }


  $("#slideContainer").on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var delta = e.delta || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
    var zoomOut;
    if (delta === undefined) {
      delta = e.originalEvent.detail;
      zoomOut = delta ? delta < 0 : e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0;
      zoomOut = !zoomOut;
    } else {
      zoomOut = delta ? delta < 0 : e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0;
    }
    if (zoomOut) {
      translateZ = translateZ - stepZ;
    } else {
      translateZ = translateZ + stepZ;
    }
    apply_coords();

  });


  var is_dragging = false;
  $("#slideContainer")
    .mousedown(function(e) {
      is_dragging = true;
    })
    .mousemove(function(e) {
      if (is_dragging) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var currentX = e.type === 'touchend' ? e.changedTouches[0].pageX : e.pageX;
        var currentY = e.type === 'touchend' ? e.changedTouches[0].pageY : e.pageY;
        translateX = initial_obj_X + (currentX - initial_mouse_X);
        translateY = initial_obj_Y + (currentY - initial_mouse_Y);
        apply_coords();
      } else {
        initial_mouse_X = e.type === 'touchend' ? e.changedTouches[0].pageX : e.pageX;
        initial_mouse_Y = e.type === 'touchend' ? e.changedTouches[0].pageY : e.pageY;
        initial_obj_X = translateX;
        initial_obj_Y = translateY;
      }
    })
    .mouseup(function() {
      is_dragging = false;
    });


});
```

```css
#slideContainer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideContainer">
  <div id="slide">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm stuck with scale because I was trying to enhance iDangerous swiper zoom and they use scale

Answer (score 0):

The code I use to zoom in at the mouse position is below. It does not use `transform` / `translate3d` but readjusts the position of the image within the div and adjusts its `height` and `width`.

```js
var zoom = 1;
var img, div;
window.onload = function() {
  window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false)
  img = document.getElementById("img");
  div = document.getElementById("div");
}

function wheel(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var delta = 0;
  if (!event) /* For IE. */
    event = window.event;
  if (event.wheelDelta) { /* IE/Opera. */
    delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
  } else if (event.detail) { /** Mozilla case. */
    /** In Mozilla, sign of delta is different than in IE.
     * Also, delta is multiple of 3.
     */
    delta = -event.detail / 3;
  }
  /** If delta is nonzero, handle it.
   * Positive Delta = wheel scrolled up,
   * Negative Delte = wheel scrolled down.
   */
  if (delta) {
    // will pass 1 to zoom in and -1 to zoom out     
    delta = delta / Math.abs(delta)
    zoomImage(delta == 1, event);
  }
}

function zoomImage(zoomIn, e) {
  var oldZoom = zoom;
  var direction = 1 * (zoomIn ? 1 : -1);
  zoom += direction * .2;
  // range = 50% => 600%
  zoom = round(Math.min(6, Math.max(.5, zoom)), 1);
  
  if (zoom == 1) {
    // For a zoom = 1, we reset
    resetZoom(div, img);
    return;
  }

  // make the position of the mouse the center, 
  // or as close as can with keeping maximum image viewable
  // e == div[this.slide]
  // gets the top and left of the div
  var divOffset = getOffset(div);
  var imgStyles = getComputedStyle(img);
  var divStyles = getComputedStyle(div);
  var imgOffset = {
    x: parseInt(imgStyles.left),
    y: parseInt(imgStyles.top)
  };

  // where clicked relative in div
  var yTravel = e.pageY - divOffset.y;
  var xTravel = e.pageX - divOffset.x;

  // where clicked
  var xOldImg = -imgOffset.x + xTravel;
  var yOldImg = -imgOffset.y + yTravel;

  // the clicked position relative to the image 0,0
  // clicked position will remain at the cursor position while image zoom changes

  // calc the same position at the new zoom level
  var ratio = zoom / oldZoom;
  var xNewImg = xOldImg * ratio;
  var yNewImg = yOldImg * ratio;

  // calc new top / left
  var xStart = -(xNewImg - xTravel);
  var yStart = -(yNewImg - yTravel);

  img.style.height = parseInt(divStyles.height) * (zoom) + "px";
  img.style.width = parseInt(divStyles.width) * (zoom) + "px";

  img.style.top = yStart + "px";
  img.style.left = xStart + "px";
  img.style.cursor = "grab";
}

function resetZoom(div, img) {
  img.style.top = "0px";
  img.style.left = "0px";
  img.style.height = div.style.height;
  img.style.width = div.style.width;
  img.style.cursor = "default";
  zoom = 1;
}

function getOffset(element) {
  var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  var posX = rect.left + window.pageXOffset; // alias for window.scrollX; 
  var posY = rect.top + window.pageYOffset; // alias for window.scrollY; 

  return {
    x: posX,
    y: posY,
    left: posX,
    top: posY,
    width: rect.width,
    height: rect.height
  };
}

function round(number, precision) {
  precision = precision ? +precision : 0;

  var sNumber = number + '',
    periodIndex = sNumber.indexOf('.'),
    factor = Math.pow(10, precision);

  if (periodIndex === -1 || precision < 0) {
    return Math.round(number * factor) / factor;
  }

  number = +number;

  // sNumber[periodIndex + precision + 1] is the last digit
  if (sNumber[periodIndex + precision + 1] >= 5) {
    // Correcting float error
    // factor * 10 to use one decimal place beyond the precision
    number += (number < 0 ? -1 : 1) / (factor * 10);
  }

  return +number.toFixed(precision);
}
```

```css
#div {
  width: 350px;
  height: 262px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#img {
  width: 350px;
  height: 262px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id='div'>
  <img id='img' src="https://www.design.mseifert.com/git-slideshow/img-demo/images01.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: I'm stuck with translate because was trying to enhance iDangerous swiper zoom, and they use translate.