# Zooming an image on GWT on a certain spot

Tags: java, gwt, zooming, gxt

Is there a way to zoom on a GWT image on a certain spot. Like on Google Maps. If you scroll on the part where your mouse pointer is, the image will zoom in that spot.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick. Based on [this JS response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46647138/zoom-in-on-a-mousewheel-point-using-scale-and-translate). Full source code [here](https://github.com/ibaca/gsg-hello-app/blob/wheelzoom/src/main/java/me/client/App.java).

```
EventType.bind(document, wheel, new EventCallbackFn<WheelEvent>() {
    double[] pos = {0, 0};
    double scale = 1;
    @Override
    public void onEvent(WheelEvent ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        // cap the delta to [-1,1] for cross browser consistency
        double delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, ev.deltaY / 200.));
        // determine the point on where the img is zoomed in
        double[] zoomTarget = {(ev.pageX - pos[0]) / scale, (ev.pageY - pos[1]) / scale};
        // calculate zoom and x and y based on it
        scale = Math.max(.1, Math.min(10, scale + delta * scale));
        pos[0] = -zoomTarget[0] * scale + ev.pageX;
        pos[1] = -zoomTarget[1] * scale + ev.pageY;
        target.style.transform = "translate(" + pos[0] + "px ," + pos[1] + "px) scale(" + scale + ")";
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it ouy later! :)