# How to zoom elements keeping current element position

Tags: javascript, button, zooming

I have A4 pages (sections) wrapped inside a div and a nav with zoom buttons (in, out, reset).
My trouble is that, for example, when I'm on the fifth page (text pink) and zoom in using my button, I see another page (text blue), then I have to scroll to find my fifth page again. I would like to stay on the same position, just like the browser zoom does.

I couldn't find an answer to my question. Any help is welcomed !

See my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/clairezita/s7o018tp/11/) or [CodePen](https://codepen.io/claire-lavigne/pen/OJVYXZN)

```js
$(".collapse").collapse({
  toggle: false
});

// A4 RESPONSIVE
function adjustZoom() {
  var documentWidth = window.innerWidth;
  var documentHeight = window.innerHeight;
  var zoomWidth = documentWidth / (23 * 37.795276);
  var zoomHeight = documentHeight / (31.7 * 37.795276);
  var zoomLevel = Math.min(zoomWidth, zoomHeight);
  // stop zooming when book fits page
  if (zoomLevel >= 1) return;
  $(".wrapperEBD").css({
    // removing blur
    transform: "scale(" + zoomLevel + ") perspective(1px)",
    "-webkit-font-smoothing": "antialiased"
  });
  // BUTTONS ZOOM IN - OUT
  $(".zoom").on("click", function() {
    zoomLevel += 0.1;
    $(".wrapperEBD").css({
      transform: "scale(" + zoomLevel + ")"
    });
  });
  $(".zoom-out").on("click", function() {
    zoomLevel -= 0.1;
    $(".wrapperEBD").css({
      transform: "scale(" + zoomLevel + ")"
    });
  });
}
window.addEventListener("load", adjustZoom);

// RIGHT NAV FIXED EVEN ZOOMING
function noZoom() {
  $(".indice-right").css({
    top: "5%",
    right: "3%",
    width: "3em"
  });
}
noZoom();
window.addEventListener("resize", noZoom);

// BUTTON RESET
$(".zoom-init").on("click", function() {
  adjustZoom();
});
```

```css
.indice-right {
  z-index: 99;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  zoom: reset;
  top: 5%;
  right: 3%;
  width: 3em;
}

#bodyEBD {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: grey;
  height: 100vh;
}

#bodyEBD * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#bodyEBD .wrapperEBD {
  transform-origin: top;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.ebook-page {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  padding: 2cm;
  margin: 0.5cm;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.2);
  outline: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.ebook-page p {
  text-align: justify;
}

.ebook-page img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.ebook-page:nth-of-type(1) {
  color: red;
}

.ebook-page:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: blue;
}

.ebook-page:nth-of-type(3) {
  color: green;
}

.ebook-page:nth-of-type(4) {
  color: orange;
}

.ebook-page:nth-of-type(5) {
  color: pink;
}

.ebook-page:nth-of-type(6) {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body id="bodyEBD">

  <nav class="indice-right">
    <a class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseIndiceRight" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseIndiceRight">
      <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseIndiceRight">
      <a class="btn zoom"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      <a class="btn zoom-out"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
      <a class="btn zoom-init"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></a>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="wrapperEBD">
    <section id="one" class="ebook-page">
      <img src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/jcr_content/main-pars/image/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_intro.jpg" alt="" />
      <h3>TITLE</h2>
        <h3>SUBTITLE</h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </p>
    </section>
    <section id="two" class="ebook-page">
      <img src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/jcr_content/main-pars/image/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_intro.jpg" alt="" />
      <h3>TITLE</h2>
        <h3>SUBTITLE</h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </p>
    </section>
    <section id="one" class="ebook-page">
      <img src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/jcr_content/main-pars/image/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_intro.jpg" alt="" />
      <h3>TITLE</h2>
        <h3>SUBTITLE</h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </p>
    </section>
    <section id="two" class="ebook-page">
      <img src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/jcr_content/main-pars/image/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_intro.jpg" alt="" />
      <h3>TITLE</h2>
        <h3>SUBTITLE</h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </p>
    </section>
    <section id="one" class="ebook-page">
      <img src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/jcr_content/main-pars/image/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_intro.jpg" alt="" />
      <h3>TITLE</h2>
        <h3>SUBTITLE</h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </p>
    </section>
    <section id="two" class="ebook-page">
      <img src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/jcr_content/main-pars/image/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_intro.jpg" alt="" />
      <h3>TITLE</h2>
        <h3>SUBTITLE</h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </p>
    </section>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30039971/1169519) doesn't fit to your code (which you should add to the question itself), but explains well what you need to do.

Comment: @Teemu, Yes, I'm not sure it will help me as it takes the current mouse position, but I'll take a look.